# Split Excel file into Chink of specified records and account for column data group

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below requirement where I have one big Excel sheet as input to my NodeJs program and

> 1# - I have to split it on each less than equal to 60K records.
>
> 2# - Column B where we have invoice number, which can repeat. During same
> split invoice number should not spill into next split sheet.

In below given example GH26025 cannot be part of next sheet.

How to achieve it in JavaScript. I need this Invoice based Split logic and ensure count not going more than 60K (or can have couple more or count back which ever easy, i have flexibility).

**One way i** can think off is - when you reach count 60K in counter check next record if that is not same as 60K th record than we are good, if it is same read more till current record finish or reverse way.

```
**Split#1**
14-Jul-2018     GH26023
14-Jul-2018     GH26024
14-Jul-2018     GH26024
14-Jul-2018     GH26024
14-Jul-2018     GH26025
14-Jul-2018     GH26025
14-Jul-2018     GH26025
14-Jul-2018     GH260**25**

**Split 2**
14-Jul-2018     GH26026
14-Jul-2018     GH26026
14-Jul-2018     GH26027
15-Jul-2018     GH26027
15-Jul-2018     GH260**28**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the result with below pseudo steps after declaring some required variables like StartPosition, Boundary, Limit etc:

- Count the total rows of given excel
- Define variable for limit which you want to allow for processing in chunk
- Check if limit.INVOICE_NO == limit-1.INVOICE_NO
- if yes
- loop until get same INVOICE NO where INVOICE_NO not match record that position
- slice the array from start to not match position
- if no
- move to next number and repeat above to slice array
- set starting pos variable as boundary variable
- all sliced array will be stored in one array
- write to separate files

It worked fine. Thanks!!